# Using DependencyProperty to Display Placeholder Text on a TextBox (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, dependency-properties

I have a custom user control which consists only a TextBox, I want to be able to bing a Placeholder text to that Textbox. My UserControl code is like this

```
<UserControl
x:Class="Proj.Editors.EditTextControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MemberSuiteConsoleApp.Controls.Editors"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtbox"  Width="300" PlaceholderText="{Binding ElementName=txtbox, Path=DataContext.PlaceholderText}"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

```
public sealed partial class EditTextControl : UserControl
    {
        public EditTextControl()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string PlaceholderText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(PlaceholderTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PlaceholderTextProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for PlaceholderText.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PlaceholderTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("PlaceholderText", typeof(string), typeof(EditTextControl), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    }
```

And I am trying to use this UserControl in my page like this in my Page

```
 <Grid>
    <editors:EditTextControl PlaceholderText="My placeholder" Height="400"></editors:EditTextControl>
</Grid>
```

But for some reason, Placeholder text is not showing in Textbox, What I am missing here?

Comment: Usually I would generate placeholder text, using a converter. The VM's value being null, empty string or the like would be conerted to the placeholder text.

Comment: @Christopher placeholder  is a beginning I have a lot of other properties too to make a dependency, That's why I am trying to solve one first. So I can follow the process for the others

Comment: Nothing prevents you from using one converter on several bindings. As long as all those properties have the same way to anotate "no value" or "waiting for user input", that is.

Comment: Ok. On your first comment, you talked about VM's value being NULL, But in my case, I am directly assigning Placeholder text in XAML itself, will it then affected by VM value?

Comment: I did not even realise there was a property for it, but I should have guessed. Then of course, you do not need a converter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.placeholdertext At least as I read the Property descroption, the PlaceHolder text should be displayed as long as the values does not *change*. Propably meaning "changed away from whatever the binding first retreived". I am not sure how it would react to stuff like the user deleting the input (even if that does not restore the exact starting value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use x:Bind instead. I tried and works.

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtbox"  Width="300" PlaceholderText="{x:Bind PlaceholderText, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBox>
```